# how to Syncronizing build modifier with object constraint follow the path

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

how do to animate Image as plane with follow the path/ curve along with build modifier at same starting point and animation speed

The following are the steps I have tried but the results are not as expected

1. on 1st layer i draw letters and add build modifier
2. convert 1st layer to bezier curve so its make 2nd layer ( the curves layer )
3. add image as plane ( pencil png )
4. add empty plain axes, and set it to the image
5. Move the image into empty plain axes
6. Add empty plain axes object constraint (follow the path) with target 2nd layer (the curves layer )
   the results that im expecting is the pencil png animation looks writing the letters animation.
   How to achieve that rather than do manually frame by frame

below is the animation result:
[image]

Comment: can u pls add an animation/gif/link how your end result should look like? thx. I am not sure whether you just want to animate a pen writing text...if yes, you don't need a build modifier...

Comment: i forgot didnt tell that im working on 2d animation, if i dont add build modifier so how could i to animate the letters drawing?

Comment: i would just animate a curve...you could use "trim curve" node of geometry nodes e.g. or trim the curve "traditionally" e.g. with add-ons